# How to "repeat-x" a sprite, generated by Compass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, css-sprites, compass-sass

I have a `gradient` directory in my `assets/images` in a Rails 3.1 application. Here's the code I use to create a sprite from those images using Compass:

```
 $gradient-repeat: repeat-x;
 @import "compass";
 @import "gradient/*.png";
 body > header > nav {
   clear: both;
   @include gradient-sprite(red-menu);
 }
```

My problem is that even though I explicitly tell Compass that I want my background to be repeated horizontally, it still produces the following CSS:

```
 body > header > nav {
   clear: both;
   background-position: 0 -207px;
   height: 34px;
 }
 .gradient-sprite, body > header > nav {
   background: url(/assets/gradient-sbe06665f77.png) no-repeat;
 }
```

and so my gradient does not get repeated horizontally.

I'm using the 3.1 branch of the Compass gem in my Gemfile.

Now, I could simply add a `background-repeat: repeat-x;` to my code and override what Compass has generated for me, but that I feel is not the Rails way of doing things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1. COMPASS, Y U NO REPEAT MY BACKGROUNDS. Note: Compass WILL repeat your image to fill the sprite width, which is probably why many people don't notice this problem — it only pops up if your sprite is narrower than the element you want to repeat the background of.

Comment: Probably not many people use compass to generate gradient sprites and maybe that is why this hasn't been noticed... :). Maybe we should file a bug report on github?

Comment: I think you should definitely do that. I use compass for this a lot, but never have narrow enough sprites that it becomes an issue.